# How to solve this Chomsky Form

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

```
S → aSab | ABB | BB

A → baab | BABB | AaA

B → bAaBa | bb | b
```

I started solving it but it seems I just kept on adding new rules to keep up, can someone please explain how to do this one.

Comment: i got something like this but i am pretty sure its wrong. S0=S, S=AD|BB, A=BL|AM|FO, B=b|FF|FT, K=a,F=b,D=BB,G=FF,Z=SG,L=AD,M=KA,N=KK,O=NF,I=BK,R=KI,T=AR

Answer (score 1):

This is the resulting grammar in Chomsky normal form: 
defined by a 4-tuple of set of non-terminal symbols, set of terminal symbols, rules and the start symbol, respectively.

G = ({S,A,B,<Sab>,<ab>,<BB>,<aab>,<ABB>,<aA>,<AaBa>,<aBa>,<Ba>,a',b'},{a,b},R,S)

R = 
S → a'<Sab> | A<BB> | BB 
A → b'<aab> | B<ABB> | A<aA> 
B → b'<AaBa> | b'b' | b 
<Sab> → S<ab> 
<ab> → a'b' 
<BB> → BB 
<aab> → a'<ab> 
<ABB> → A<BB> 
<aA> → a'A 
<AaBa> → A<aBa> 
<aBa> → a'<Ba> 
<Ba> → Ba' 
a' → a 
b' → b

Feel free to rename the non-terminals in angle brackets <> by one-character capital symbols as you feel appropriate (they do mean a single non-terminal character), I find this more suitable.